# Can't get this Javascript query to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The first `div` in below code displays a college name, which when clicked upon triggers the function `display_people()`. The function is used to show/hide the people of that college. The names of these people are contained inside the `div` tag with `id="college_people"` whose initial `display` is set to `none`.

Now, when a person name is clicked, it triggers the function `display_chat_box()`, which is used to show the chat-box for that person.

The chat-box appears when we click on the person's name, and there is no provision for the chat-box to disappear. But the person name itself can be hidden or displayed by the function `display_people()`. Apparently, when the person name is hidden(on clicking the college name, thus hiding back person name by using `toggle()` of jQuery), the chat-box is seen to disappear,  which I don't want.

Perhaps, this happens because the chat-box appears when the person name is clicked. And when that name disappears, its `onclick` function also disappears and hence goes off the chat-box. I just want the chat box to stay there, and not to go off along with the person name.

Is there any way I could possibly do this?

```
<div id='state_college_container' onclick='display_people()'>
  <span id='state_college_span'>
    College name
  </span>
</div>

<div id='college_people' style='display:none'>
  <div id='college_people_container' onclick='display_chat_box()'>
    <span id='college_people_span'>
      People name
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

function display_people() {
    $("#college_people").toggle();
}
function display_chat_box() {
    $(".chat_box").show();
}
```

The chat-box is located in a completely separated HTML file under the class name `chat_box`. It's not a descendant to any other element.

Here's the HTML code for chat box.

```
 <div class="chat_box">
    <div id="chat_box_bar">
    <span id="chat_with">Your name</span>
    <span id="close_chat" onclick="close_chat_box()">X</span>
    </div>
    <div id="previous_chat1" >
       <span> Hi, how are you?</span>         
    </div>
     <div id="textarea_container">
    <textarea onkeypress="return detectEnter(event)" id="chat_content1"  name="posted_content1"></textarea>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the chat box located? I don't see it in your example. If the chat box is a descendant of `#college_people` than it disappears because `#college_people` gets hidden. The solution would be to move it out of there. Otherwise, there is not enough information in your question to give you an answer. Please provide the relevant code so that we can *reproduce* the problem.

Comment: did you enclose your functions in dom ready?

Comment: If the `.chat_box` element is within the `#college_people` element then it will hide the .chat_box when you hide its parent. You haven't posted enough of a sample snippet though to tell this for sure. Is there some way you can move the `.chat_box` out of the `#college_people`?

Comment: Where is chat_box? If it is inside the name div, that will explain why it disappears

Comment: Based on what you have here, it seems that the `toggle()` is what's giving you trouble. My first inclination is that your chat box is located inside `#college_people` div which is being hidden.

Comment: Where in your html structure does `<div class='chat_box'>` lie? If it's a child of `<div id='college_people'>` that would explain why its visibility is married to that of `college_people`...

Comment: a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a working sample would be a big help here.

Comment: The chat box is a class located on another file. Its not a descendant of any other element. Its just under the <body> tag of another completely independent HTML file.

Comment: Thanks, please check my update at the end of the post.

Comment: How can the JavaScript loaded in one HTML file affect the elements of another HTML file? It sounds like what you are doing is impossible. But since the chat box does appear, it must be working somehow. So please, create a minimal, self-contained example that reproduces the problem, otherwise we cannot properly help you. We still have no idea how the elements related to each other.

Comment: Felix Kling, I am sorry to be unable to create an example for the situation. But the thing is, these are all parts of a big project based on PHP. The above code has been taken out of different files that are linked together through one single file. The JAVASCRIPT functions here are contained in a seperate JS file, and not in the HTML file. They're all connected!!

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they are different files on the server, all that matters is what the browser sees. Right click on the page `->` View source and copy the *relevant* HTML. We really cannot help you without more information. Based on what you've told us, i.e. that the chat box is a child of `body`, I can create this example http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/t4asT/, but it works as expected. How do you think we can solve the problem if we cannot even recreate it in the first place? As it is, the only reason why the chat box would disappear is if it was a descendant of `#college_people`.

Comment: Is this site online somewhere that we can visit?

Comment: #rtpHarry No, the site isn't online. I am a worker on this project, and I have no rights to publish it online whatsoever! Please help me with the details I have mentioned above, and ask me if more is required?

Comment: I already told you what we need: A more complete HTML example. If you cannot provide that then we cannot help you. I suggest to get help from a coworker instead.

Comment: Felix Kling, I am sorry I the link you posted takes forever to load(thanks to my network). However, could I make a demo video or something to help explain my problem, if that helps?

Comment: I just updated my post again with the HTML chat-box code!

Comment: Thanks for that. But still, if it is as you say, then the JavaScript code you posted is not responsible for the disappearance of the chat box (see [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/t4asT/) from my previous comment). That's all we can say. The problem might then be with the rest of the code in the page. I hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: Felix Kling, Thanks for your incredible support. But, I somehow got it to work. The problem source was the placement of chat-box code(it wasn't in the correct file). I am grateful to you all! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow got it to work. The problem source was the placement of chat-box code(it wasn't in the correct file).